# Accessing a samba 3 share from windows server 2008 r2

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, samba

I have a linux box (Ubuntu 10.04 server) that exports a couple of shares via SAMBA.
This is a very simple setup: plain workgroup sharing, no domain involved.
I can access this share from other linux boxes, from a Windows XP machine, and from a couple of Windows 7 machines (and from various Android devices) and it works like a charm.
Now I installed Windows Server 2008 r2 on a partition of the Windows XP machine and when I boot into WS2008r2 I cannot access the shares. The server is not listed in the network resources and typing \\server-name\share or \\server-ip\share just returns a 0x80004005 error code.
I've seen people complaining about KB2536276 and I uninstalled it, but to no avail...
Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Oh well, I just re-installed WS2008r2 and now I can access the share...